# Help solving a D. E using Linear Equation solving method

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following equation and need to use linear equation method to solve this

$$  y' + 5y = 2 $$

(Do not use separable equation method for this please)

Comment: Is it clear to you what the "method" is?  The answer could be instructor dependent, but probably is not. You need to (a) find the *general* solution of the homogeneous equation $y'+5y=0$, probably by trying $y=e^{rx}$ and (b) find a *particular* solution of $y'+5y=2$ (easy).

Comment: "Linear equation method" means to use a certain formula?  What is that formula?

Comment: Integrating factors? I don't know what you mean by this question at all...

Comment: I think we just have to wait until user10695 comes back and tells us what he means by "linear equation method".

Answer (score 1):

The question suprises me a little, since it seems more basic than other DE questions that you have asked in the past.  I will give an answer so as not to leave it unanswered. There have been a number of posts on linear differential equations on this site, but they all seem to involve equations that are *harder* than this one.  Perhaps it is worthwhile to show how things work in a very simple case.

The given equation is a first order linear differential equation with constant coefficients.  A general procedure for solving linear differential equations goes as follows.

($1$.)  Find the *general* solution $y_g$ of the differential equation obtained by setting the term not containing $y$, $y'$ (and $y''$, $y'''$, and so on if they occur) equal to $0$.  So in our case we want to find the general solution of the DE $y'+5y=0$.

($2$.) Find a *particular* solution $y_p$ of the original equation.

Then the general solution of our equation is $y_p +y_g$.

**A particular solution**: In this case, finding a particular solution is easy.  We look for a *constant* function $y_p$, because then we will have $y_p'=0$.  So we want $5y_p=2$, giving $y_p=\frac{2}{5}$.

**The general solution of the homogeneous equation**:  The usual procedure is to look for solutions of the shape $y=e^{rx}$, where $r$ is a constant.  In our case, we want to have
$$y'+5y=0.$$
Let $y=e^{rx}$ and calculate. We obtain
$$re^{5x}+5e^{rx}=0.$$
This equation holds identically precisely if $r+5=0$.  So we conclude that $r=-5$.

Thus $y=e^{rx}$ is a solution of the homogeneous DE.  The *general* solution of the homogeneous DE is given by 
$$y_g=Ce^{-5x},$$
where $C$ is any constant.

Thus the general solution of the original DE is given by
$$y=\frac{2}{5}+Ce^{-5x}.$$

**Remark**: The same basic calculation, "particular solution plus general solution of the homogeneous DE" is valid for general linear differential equations. The details can become considerably harder.